# Code contracts checking thread affinity - good idea?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, code-contracts

I'm trying to learn Code Contracts and get an idea of for what are they useful.

I have a WPF application, so a lot of code is bound to run exclusively on the UI thread. Quite a few utility classes expect to be called from the UI thread only.

Is it good idea so sprinkle these through my code? Why yes/not?

```
Contract.Requires(Thread.CurrentThread == Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread);
```

Will the static checker be able to reliably check these?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right to want to make these affinity checks.  They are a great way to spot subtle bugs early but not something that can be checked statically using code contracts as mentions by *Henk* and *decyclone*.

I have a static class called `Ensure` with a method `Ensure.OnUiThread()` that contains the exact same check as you mention. I mark this with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` so as not to slow/bloat production code.  Works nicely for me.

Comment: It is possible to do some static checking for this. It can't be complete for public methods, but it can be determined when something marked as restricted to one class of thread calls something marked as restricted to an incompatible class of thread. For example, if I make up an attribute and have `[ThreadRestriction("UI")]void UiThing() { // bad } [ThreadRestriction("Background")]void BackgroundThing() { UiThing(); }`, a static checker could detect that BackgroundThing should not call ForegroundThing. Microsoft's contracts do not seem to provide this.

Answer (score 2):

Your contracts should be about your code. The Dispatcher and Thread classes aren't yours and they're not guarded by contracts of their own.

So No, the static checker won't be able to check this at all.

The runtime checks might work but they add little to the Debug checks already built into the library.

Answer (score 1):

A contract for a method is *"for a specific valid input, given method will produce a valid output"*.

In your case, you are not validating the *Input* of your method. That is why I would not recommend using this approach.

In other words, this would not be a contract but just some sort of validation/assertion.